# Composer error when installing Laravel 4 - '.../doctrine/dbal/f279c2aecfef9095e6b25 75f568d411b' is not a zip archive

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I'm trying to get my Laravel 4 running for the first time here, using WampServer2 in Windows XP environment. I have already enabled the php_openssl.dll.

When I issue "composer install" on the Laravel root directory, it start the installation by installing the filp/whoops, then doctrine. Problem happens in doctrine:

```
D:\My Box Files\webdev\laravel4>composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing filp/whoops (1.0.7)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Installing doctrine/lexer (dev-master bc0e1f0)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Installing doctrine/annotations (v1.1.2)
    Downloading: 100%

  ...
  ...

  - Installing doctrine/dbal (dev-master fbce4b5)
    Downloading: 100%



  [UnexpectedValueException]
  'D:\My Box Files\webdev\laravel4\vendor/doctrine/dbal/0385cd8ce14f51b82fc70
  029e8890ac0' is not a zip archive.
```

Anyone has any idea why is this happening?

Comment: Check your composer version with `composer -V`. I recommend you update to the latest version with `composer selfupdate`, try again, and let us know. (Right now latest version is "d740f502772929d127f6d58e4f5a71463b1147e6".)

Comment: It's already the latest: D:\My Box Files\webdev\laravel4>composer -V
Composer version d740f502772929d127f6d58e4f5a71463b1147e6

Comment: Please read ddebree comment here: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1242

Comment: You can also run `composer diagnose` to check for issues.

Comment: After change to my office network, it install with no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1242 it may be network-related or corrupted cached files:

> The problem is that Composer caches (in my case corrupted) files and
>   so whenever you run the command it just reuses these corrupted files.
>   It never downloads fresh versions of the file.  The solution is to
>   delete the cache files and rerun the command. The cache files are in
>   the composer home directory:
>   https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-home under the
>   cache.files folder.

You can see the exact location of your composer cache files using the `config` command:

```
composer config --list
```